# Does it make sense to have a control group for a school chemistry experiment?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment

I'm wondering if it makes sense to have a control group for the following experiment:

- measure the speed of gas produced  when hydrochloric acid and calcium carbonate react, as a function of surface area of the calcium carbonate.
- independent variable: coarseness of calcium carbonate ($\ce{CaCO3}$) as a way to control the surface area of the $\ce{CaCO3}$ from large chips down to powder.
- dependent variable: speed of glass production measured using water displacement in a calibrated volume.

Usually I think of a control group as being used to control uncontrollable variations in the experiment, especially in biology or psychology experiments. But in this case, assuming that the volumes of $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{CaCO3}$ are measured carefully, and the gas is accurately measured, are there other variables that a control group would assist with?

We know that there will be an effect of mixing $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{CaCO3}$. We can hypothesize that increased surface area will speed the reaction. But does it make any sense to have a control where we mix $\ce{CaCO3}$ and water? Or $\ce{HCl}$ and pieces of unreactive glass?

Comment: A control where you only mix HCl and water will show you the baseline: You should observe some volume expansion as the mixture get warm, due to the heat liberated on dilution of the acid. 
Otherwise, I'd opt for replicates, as you'll see some variation and it will nicely show that measured data is not absolute. Plus, you can do some statistics.

Comment: @M.Farooq if you copy your comments into an answer I would be happy to edit them.

Comment: @imalipusram if you copy your comments into an answer I would be happy to edit them.

Comment: @nilay-ghosh thank your for your edits

Comment: In your demo, you don't need any control experiment. A control experiment would have been needed if there were a competing side reaction producing a gas and affecting your gas measurement.

Comment: @JasonHarrison, I deleted my comment and copied it as an answer upon your request.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a demo experiment. If you modify your answer to include the other information that are included in the comments it would make this answer complete